# Sending a message to HornetQ in one JBoss AS 7 server from a SFSB in another JBoss AS 7

Tags: ejb-3.0, javabeans, jboss7.x, jndi, hornetq

I'm having a hard time getting this to work. Here is my setup

Server1 - JBoss AS 7.1 - Bean1, Bean2 (stateful session beans)

Server2 - JBoss AS 7.1 - HornetQ, MDB1

The idea is to send a message to HornetQ on Server2 from Bean1. I just can't believe it is this difficult. I have tried everything under the sun, but it just doesn't work. The fundamental issue I see is that the JNDI lookup that I'm doing in Bean1 is pointing to Server1 instead of Server2. And hence I get a queue not found exception when I do a look up for the queue. I've also tried starting AS with -b option pointing to Server2. How do I do a JNDI lookup of Server2/HornetQ from Server1/Bean1?

I'm, however, able to send a message to the same queue from a standalone console application (that has nothing to do with JBoss AS 7 at all). The JNDI lookup works perfectly fine when I do it from a console application.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

You have to lookup from a remote JNDI.

I'm not sure ATM how to specifying jndiProps.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "127.0.0.1:4447"); in one of the JNDI Properties.

**Option 2:**

you could create a local Pooled connection factory bound to the remote server:

First specify a connector:

```
<connectors>
     <netty-connector name="remote-jms" socket-binding="messaging-remote"/>
   ...   
</connectors>
```

And also specify the socket binding:

```
<socket-binding-group ....>
....
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-jms">
        <remote-destination host="other-hos" port="5445"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

And then specify the pooled connection factory that will be connected remotely.

```
<pooled-connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory1">
     <user>jmsuser</user>
     <password>jmspassword</password>
     <connectors>
          <connector-ref connector-name="remote-jms" />
     </connectors>
     <entries>
          <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory1" />
     </entries>
</pooled-connection-factory>
```

**Option 3:**

Create the connection factory without using JNDI. Notice that you will perform a network call every time you connect. the best would be to pool a connection:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/using-jms.html#d0e1361